# What are the preconditions to fit a vector autoregression model?

Tags: time-series, assumptions, vector-autoregression

can we fit a VAR model if we have a mixture of I(0) and I(1) variables?

Comment: There are a bunch of similar questions already and yours is likely a duplicate. Check out some of [these](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bvar%5D+I%280%29).